# How to simplify the following modulo operation

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am trying to find the modulo of an expression. All I know is that

```
(a+b) mod N = ((a mod N) + (b mod N)) mod N
```

How do I use it to simplify the following modulo operation?

```
(a - 2*b + 1) mod N
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to get it down to your basic form you put forth in the first line, then just calculate $a  \hbox{ mod }  N$ and $(2*b \hbox{ mod } N)$, and use your equality expression you stated in the beginning, noting that addition and subtraction are both equally valid when you are distributing the modulus operator, i.e. $(a - x) \hbox{ mod } N = (a \hbox{ mod } N - x \hbox{ mod } N) \hbox{ mod } N$, and $-y = N - y \hbox{ mod } N$.

Comment: What about the 1?

Comment: @W.W.: You can add the one just like you add $(a+b) \bmod n$.  Just replace $b$ with 1.

Comment: You can repeat the same operation. Suppose $a-2b mod N = c$ then calculate $c+1 mod N=w$